# MySql: get MIN record in INNER JOIN If a field is null, or change criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a query between two tables.

First table is a list of users

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | expire_on |
+----+-------+-----------+
| 22 | JOHN  | (null)    |
| 44 | SMITH | (null)    |
| 55 | DOE   | 5         |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Where "expire_on" can be NULL, but if compiled it is the expire of his subscription, in days.

And I have a list of transactions:

```
+----+----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
| id | id_member_card | amount_original | amount_final | description |       utc_date_t       |
+----+----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  1 |             22 |              12 |           12 | (null)      | 2017-05-01T10:11:12Z |
|  2 |             22 |              50 |           50 | (null)      | 2018-02-01T10:20:30Z |
|  3 |             44 |               7 |            7 | (null)      | 2018-02-02T07:50:40Z |
|  4 |             22 |               9 |            9 | (null)      | 2018-03-01T10:00:14Z |
|  5 |             44 |               5 |            5 | (null)      | 2018-03-03T08:09:10Z |
|  6 |             22 |               0 |            0 | RENEW       | 2018-05-02T11:22:33Z |
|  7 |             55 |              12 |           12 | (null)      | 2018-05-03T10:20:30Z |
+----+----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

I have this starting points:

1) The user "expires" after 365 days of his very first transaction. The id 44 will expire on the 02-02-2019... > BUT >

2) If the user has a field "expire_on", he expires after the X days and not anymore the 365. In my example, id 55 **is expired** on the 07-05-2018.

3) If in the transaction list there is a RENEW, the user expires 365 days after this transaction renew and not anymore from the first one. Id 22 will expire only on the 02-05-2019 (pratically, we could consider a RENEW transaction as his first_transaction, if this can help to write a smarter query  ) > BUT

If the user has the expire_on set, he expires X days after this renew (if the id 22 had expire_on set on, for example, let's say, 10 days, he would be expired on 12-05-2018 and not anymore 02-05-2019).

I hope that I'm clear.

Now MySql query, that I cannot complete considering the RENEW or not.

First of all, this is the link to the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16a3a/1

And this is the query:

```
SELECT member_card.id AS id,
member_card.name,
member_card.expire_on,
ts1.* FROM member_card

INNER JOIN ( 

SELECT member_card.id,
MIN(transaction.utc_date_t) AS first_transaction,
MAX(transaction.utc_date_t) AS last_transaction,

IFNULL ( 

    DATE(DATE_ADD(MAX(transaction.utc_date_t), INTERVAL expire_on DAY)) ,

    DATE(DATE_ADD(MAX(transaction.utc_date_t), INTERVAL 365 DAY)) 

    )

    AS final_expire ,


SUM(transaction.amount_final) AS balance
FROM transaction
INNER JOIN member_card ON transaction.id_member_card = member_card.id
GROUP BY member_card.id ) AS ts1 ON member_card.id = ts1.id
WHERE ( final_expire BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-28' )
GROUP BY member_card.id
```

With my query, I would expect to find id 44, because his first transaction is made on 2018-02-01, so he will expire on the february 2019. But my query considers only LAST transaction (see MAX aggregate).

So, I need to search and looking for:

1. If exists a RENEW:
2. If yes, take this date and sum 365 (OR the custom expire date)
3. If no, take MIN transaction.

Thank you very much for your support.

**Tryng to solve**

I could also get the last renew transactions, with another query:

```
SELECT id_member_card , MAX(utc_date_t) AS last_transaction_renew
FROM transaction
WHERE description IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id_member_card
```

and substitute these found id_member_card to the others, using this `last_transaction_renew` inside that IFNULL, but, how?

Comment: How about LEAST()

Comment: What should the desired result look like? Edit your question accordingly